# Layout that fixes all the content to the window width, except for large data tables

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, user-experience

#### Goal

I am trying to implement a layout that works as follows:

- Page content is responsive and adjusts to window width
- If the page contains a large data table, the table will overflow to the right
- In this case, a scroll bar on the window (not on the table) will be shown
- If the user now scrolls to the right, only the table scrolls, not the rest of the page
- Sidebar, header, footer (all with fixed height/width) should be present

#### Example

Here is a jsbin with a very hacky implementation, that should illustrate what I mean: http://jsbin.com/gonezaqala/1/edit?html,css,js,output

#### Issues

Frequent problems that I ran into:

- I figured that I need to use `position: sticky` to make this layout work but since elements are only ever sticky relative to their parent, I need to try to keep the sticky elements at a top level
- Alternatively, I can create a separate container that does the horizontal scrolling (like in the jsbin example), but then trying to make this fit with the other parts of the layout (sidebar, footer) because really painful
- I also want to implement this in a way that all the elements in the main content area (so everything but header, footer, sidebar) are together in one single container, since I am using AngularJS and this is where my router would inject the view

#### Question

I am sure, I have seen this kind of behaviour before, but I can't remember where it was. So my questions are as follows:

- Is this a somewhat common UI pattern? Does it have a name?
- Is it possible to implement a layout like this with only CSS?
- Would it anyway be desirable to create such a layout or are there any concerns from a UX perspective?

Comment: From a UX perspective, I'd think you'd want the scroll bar as close to the thing that's scrolling as possible.